# Change background color of circular button android

Tags: android, button, background-color

I have a button in android which I have made circular in shape. Also I have an xml which changes the background color on pressed, but the color goes back to normal after the pressed state is changed.

I made the following change to code

arg0.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.greenText));

But now the background takes rectangular shape and not the oval shape.

Comment: Make a new shape drawable with the pressed color and set your background to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay as you have said the background shape changes when using `setBackgroundColor`, i think here's what you want,

1.you might be interested in color filters like this

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFAA0000));
```

You use different values according to your required colour.If you want to know the constant values of colours, you can refer [the documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).

2.you can programmatically set the shade of the entire button using the PorterDuff multiply mode. This will change the button colour rather than just the tint.

For example for a red shaded button

```
btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

For a green shaded button

```
btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

And so on.What it actually does is, it works by multiplying the current button colour value by your colour value.

3.You can also use an online tool like [this Android Button Maker](http://angrytools.com/android/button/) to customize your button and use `android:background="@drawable/custom_btn"` in your layout(inside the  tag) to define the customized button.

Now i believe there are more ways to achieve what you want but i think these are some easy and quick fixes you can use.Hope this helps.

Comment: I used `new LightingColorFilter(0xFF000000, 0xFFAA0000)` to replace the color