# Android xml button has a fine border to it

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, button

First time having a go at a android app.

I added a button to the interface using XML . Set the stlye to standard Widget.Button .

The XML for the button :

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:text="Help me !"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
```

I can't post a picture because of low reputation.*

How can I remove the small lines that are surrounding the button?

The selected theme is Material Black if that helps with anything .

Comment: you don't need style attribute here

Comment: Kindly refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25795494/2319542) of mine. If it helps you then don't forget to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your own xml style file and place it in drawable folder like below...(for example style1.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#31B6E7" />    
<stroke android:width="1.5dp" //This change the surrounding lines width
    android:color="#31B6E7" />

<corners
android:radius="2dp"/>

</shape>
```

And set your style  in button..

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/Button"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:backgroung="@drawable/style1"
     android:text="Help me !"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
 />
```

Comment: Thanks , I made your solution and it removed the border . All that's left now is to modify it to my taste .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the border behind button use this
 style="?android:attr/borderlessButonStyle"

Comment: Ok , but what if I want to use the default style also ? I can't use duplicate style tag ...

Comment: This will only override your default style in your button,  you will have your default style in your button just replace your style with this