# android studio - I want to change background color of circular button

Tags: android, button

[image]I'm making a circular button that changes its color and keep it.

I'm trying to use

```
button.etBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.color));
```

But in this case, new color makes not circle but square.

I have read

[Change background color of circular button android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795278/change-background-color-of-circular-button-android)

But i couldn't understand and there is no specific explanation.

what should i do?

Comment: setColorFilter() is used to change the color pixel. It would be better if you read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter). If you are confused to this then better create a new resource xml for round color button of circular type and then use that in the button background.

Comment: sorry but this isn't for my problem ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your button background color by setting background tint color, like bellow

```
button.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#00FFAA"))); // Just replace code with your color code
```

It will work for you.